# The use of class type parameters in generic method

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a generic class intended to keep values for different kinds of properties. I want to provide a type-safe way to set property values, so that it is impossible to assign property a value of wrong type.

I defined an interface to be implemented for all property kinds:

```
public interface Property<T> {

}
```

where type parameter T is used to specify the type of property value. Then assuming the class `OrderProperty` implements this interface properties can be defined like

```
OrderProperty property1 = new OrderProperty<String>();
OrderProperty property2 = new OrderProperty<Integer>();
```

Initially I implemented the class to hold property values like

```
public class Properties<K extends Property> {

    private Map<K, Object> properties = new HashMap<K, Object>();

    public <V> void set(K key, V value) {
        properties.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the set() method is obviously not type-safe as it does not regard the connection between property and its value type so I could easily write something like

```
Properties orderProperties = new Properties<OrderProperty>();
OrderProperty countProperty = new OrderProperty<Integer>();
orderProperties.set(countProperty, "1");
```

and it would compile.

Type-safe implementation would be

```
public <V> void set(Property<V> key, V value) {
    properties.put(key, value);
}
```

but of course it will not not compile since key is not of generic type.

I need something like

```
public <V> void set(K<V> key, V value) {
    properties.put(key, value);
}
```

but this one is syntactically incorrect.

I am wondering if there is any way to accomplish what I need.

Comment: `private Map<T, Object> properties` why is this not `Map<String,T>`? I thought you said `T` is the type of the values. I'm confused.

Comment: T is used to name type parameter in two places: in interface Property where it refers to value type and in class Properties where T is used to indicate the kind of a property (there might be many of these like OrderProperty, ItemProperty and so on). I want to implements generic container for all of them.

Comment: I edited the post to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

Your `Properties` class would be able to support only one type of property. This is probably not what you are intending, even if this would work:

```
public class Properties<V, T extends Property<? extends V>> {
    public void set(T key, V value) {
      //...
    }
}
```

If you want to support different types of properties, then you must check the validity of your property manually. The reason for this is Java's due to [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108979):

1. Make your Property<V> aware of the actual type it is going to support
2. Check for that type in the Properties.set method

```
public interface Property<T> {
  public Class<T> getPropertyType();
}

public class OrderProperty<T> extends Property<T> {
  Class<T> type;
  /** This constructor is required due to type erasure, otherwise the OrderType doesn't know the property type */
  public OrderProperty(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  public Class<T> getPropertyType() {
    return type;
  }
}

public class Properties<K extends Property> {

    private Map<K, Object> properties = new HashMap<K, Object>();

    public <V> void set(K key, V value) {
        properties.put(key, key.getPropertyType().cast(value));
    }

}
```

Comment: I see that due to type erasure runtime checks based on type parameters are not possible. What I wanted to get was compile-type checks based on provided type parameters. In set() method K and V are sort of "dependent types" so I was wondering if it is possible to define this dependency.

While 

public class Properties<V, T extends Property<? extends V>> {
    public void set(T key, V value) {
      //...
    }
}

defines such a dependency using class type parameters, it looks like it is impossible to instantiate properties that would allow arbitrary types for V.

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway, runtime checks are better then no checks at all.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to use something as

```
public class Properties<V> {
    public void set(Property<V> key, V value) {
        properties.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

EDIT : 
Ok, based on your comment, maybe something like this should do it :

```
public class Properties<V, T extends Property<V>> {
    public void set(T key, V value) {

    }
}
```

EDIT 2 : 
To instanciate that class you can do something like

```
Properties<Integer, OrderedProperty<Integer>> properties = 
    new Properties<Integer, OrderedProperty<Integer>>
```

Comment: The problem is that Properties class is to hold properties of a single kind, so it needs to be typed with an implementation of Property interface. This way I can prevent putting say an ItemProperty into the collection of OrderProperties.

Comment: It looks like a good option, but how do I instantiate this Properties class - I mean type parameters? I tried using <? extends Object> but it didn't do - I am probably missing something.

Comment: As I commented at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194307/the-use-of-class-type-parameters-in-generic-method/3196582#3196582 Properties should allow for values of different data types contained in Property, i.e. OrderedProperty<Integer>, OrderedProperty<String> and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
Ok, sorry about that, I didn't fully understand your requirement. In your case, my previous answer was probably pretty useless. Since you want to be able  to store different properties in your `Properties` class and still have the `put(..)` method be type safe, you could have something like this:

```
public static class Properties {

    private Map<Property<?>, Object> properties = new HashMap<Property<?>, Object>();

    public <V> void put(Property<V> key, V value) {
        properties.put(key, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <V> V get(Property<V> key) {
        return (V) properties.get(key);
    }

}
```

In this case, you can only put a property and a value that match the type of that property, like so:

```
OrderProperty<String> stringProperty = new OrderProperty<String>();
OrderProperty<Integer> countProperty = new OrderProperty<Integer>();

Properties orderProperties = new Properties();
orderProperties.put(countProperty, 3);
orderProperties.put(stringProperty, "");
orderProperties.put(stringProperty, 2);//This will not compile!
```

Comment: Yes, of course I can create an instance of Properties the way you mentioned, but the matter is that it should allow for properties of different types. So for example OrderProperty<Integer> countProperty = new OrderProperty<Integer>(); orderProperties.put(countProperty, 1); and OrderProperty<String> nameProperty = new OrderProperty<String>(); orderProperties.put(nameProperty, "1"); should be possible at the same time.

Comment: If you look at the whole discussion you will see we are walking in circles ;)
Properties class itself should accept type parameter to restrict map keys to specific Property implementation.